# URLRead not working at all

Tags: data-acquisition, internet

In MMA 13.0 on Mac (Intel silicon) MacSO 12.01

```
URLRead["https://google.de"]
```

yields:

```
Failure["InvalidLocation",Association[Rule["MessageTemplate","Specified request is invalid"],Rule["MessageParameters",Association[]]]]
```

for google.de and every other working URL too. Wolfram internet based functions, e.g. alpha requests work properly.

How to solve this?

Update: in MMA Cloud it works fine. Apple silicon works fine.

Comment: Here is what I  [see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgPfx.png).

Comment: MMA Version 13.0 I see the same.

Comment: @syed which mma version are you using?

Comment: "12.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)"

Comment: Works fine for me on 13.0 for Linux.

Comment: Works for me. Windows 11 Pro, Mathematica 13.0.

Comment: Seems  to be a bug with mma13 and MacOS 12.01, after updating the OS it works now :-(

Comment: If you believe this to be a bug, please report it to Wolfram, Inc.  Thanks.